# Wrap text within a panel

Tags: python, panel

I am trying to write some text on a panel that I created, like this:

```
box.label(text="Some long text that is out of borders")
```

but because the text is too long, the panel only shows the text in one line and does not make the text stop at the edge of the panel and start a new line.

So it appears like this:

> Some long text...ers

How can I make it contained within the panel's width?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know I'am answering my own question, because I knew how to do it only after posting the question, so for anyone who may need this answer here it goes.

I used a wrap function that I made my self, like this:

```
def wrap(width, text):

  lines = []

  arr = text.split()
  lengthSum = 0

  strSum = ""

  for var in arr:
    lengthSum+=len(var) + 1
    if lengthSum <= width:
      strSum += " " + var
    else:
      lines.append(strSum)
      lengthSum = 0
      strSum = var

  lines.append(" " + arr[len(arr) - 1])

  return lines
```

The width argument is the width of the panel in terms of number of characters that fit in there.
Then in the draw function I got the width of the panel like this:

```
tool_shelf = None
area = bpy.context.area

for region in area.regions:
  if region.type == 'TOOLS':
    tool_shelf = region
```

Where tool_shelf is now the panel I created, then I call the wrap function with the width and text like this:

```
lines = wrap(math.ceil(tool_shelf.width / 9), "Some long text that is out of borders")
```

I divided by 9 because `tool_shelf.width` gives back the width in pixels, and I assumed 9 pixels for each character, now `lines` is an array where every element is a line.
Then I write the lines in the panel like this:

```
for var in lines:
  row = layout.row(align = True)
  row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
  row.label(var)
```

I know this is not the optimal way, but anybody can get the main idea from this code and optimize it to their needs.

Note: function `wrap` is not in any class, but all the other codes are inside the `draw` function of the class `Panel`.

Answer (score 14):

Another solution is to use python's [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html)  module:

```
import textwrap 

textTowrap = "Your text......................................"      
wrapp = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=50) #50 = maximum length       
wList = wrapp.wrap(text=textTowrap) 
  
#Now in the panel:
for text in wList: 
    row = layout.row(align = True)
    row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
    row.label(text=text)
```

Comment: There is no documentation in Blender's API, but this is a python module present in Blender. textwrap docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/textwrap.html

Comment: You can also add this `row.scale_y = 0.6` somewhere before `row.label(text)` so to increase or decrease the space between lines.

Answer (score 1):

I drew a script that also takes into account the resolution of the UI.

**for blender3.2**

```
import bpy
import textwrap

long_text = """
        a long text  long text  long text
        b test
        c long text  long text  long text  long text  long text  long
        d text  long text  long text  long text """

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Get the 3D View area
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                break
        # Calculate the width of the panel
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'UI':
                panel_width = region.width
                break

        # Calculate the maximum width of the label
        uifontscale = 9 * context.preferences.view.ui_scale
        max_label_width = int(panel_width // uifontscale)

        # Split the text into lines and format each line
        for line in long_text.splitlines():
            # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
            line = line.strip()

            # Split the line into chunks that fit within the maximum label width
            for chunk in textwrap.wrap(line, width=max_label_width):
                layout.label(text=chunk)

# Register the panel
bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)
```

[image]

**When the font scale is different in 2 bytes, such as Japanese**

**method part**

```
import bpy

def split_by_n(string, n):
    result = [string[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(string), n)]
    return result

def longtext_set(context,layout,long_text):
        # Get 3D viewport area
        for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                break

        # Automatically set the width of the UI region to the width of the panel
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'UI':
                panel_width = region.width
                break

        # Calculate the maximum width of the label
        font_scale= 15
        uifontscale = font_scale * context.preferences.view.ui_scale
        max_label_width = int(panel_width // uifontscale)

        save_alignment=layout.alignment

        layout.alignment = 'RIGHT'
        box = layout.box()
        # Split the text into lines and format each line
        for line in long_text.splitlines():
            # Remove leading and trailing whitespace
            line = line.strip()

            # Split the line into chunks that fit within the maximum label width
            
            for chunk in split_by_n(line, max_label_width):

            # for chunk in textwrap.wrap(line, width=max_label_width, break_long_words=False, break_on_hyphens=False):
                box.label(text=chunk)
        layout.alignment = save_alignment
```

**Depiction of panel section**

```
long_text="""
これは日本語のテスト文書です。
これは日本語のテスト文書です。
これは日本語のテスト文書です。
これは日本語のテスト文書です。
これは日本語のテスト文書です。
"""

longtext_set(context,layout=self.layout,long_text=long_text)
```