# Can I measure the UI font size with Python in order split text into multiple lines?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Is there any way to get the size of UI text, such as when using `layout.label(text="message")`?

I'm trying to create a simple message box popup that displays variable text, but the string is cut in the usual Blender way: "start...end". Which is really cool - its great for condensing UI controls into small spaces. But I'm just wanting to break the lines of text to fit into the box space.

There is a similar question here:
[Wrap text within a panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74052/wrap-text-within-a-panel) but no answers other than hard-coding the font size. And that is my primary question - how to obtain the text or font size? Or how to size the window around it?

I would really like to avoid hard-coding the glyph/text size. I'm assuming Blender does not use exactly the same font size on every display size? And there are also options for the user to set a different font for the interface. So guessing the size would break down pretty easily.

How is making a textbox usually done? Do we have to manually insert line breaks at every so many characters based on the window size? It's hard to imagine Blender implementing such a cool text condensing feature and then not including a simple one like text wrap? Maybe there is some other `label()` like function?

If not, has anyone managed to write your own text wrap type function that is reliable across different displays and user settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrap text within a panel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74052/wrap-text-within-a-panel)

Comment: I found that after posting. It's useful, but he's hard-coding the glyph size to 9 pixels. This seems like a really bad idea. Especially these days, where a screen twice as small can have twice as many pixels.

Comment: I understand that may not be the answer you want, but as far as I understand that is still the best solution. Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16197/ui-text-box-with-multiple-lines

Comment: Apparently, 5 years ago, even tool-tips didn't auto-wrap. Glad that's over. Hopefully someone out there knows some clever way to get the size of text. Personally, I don't think hard coding the text size is reliable enough to be a solution.

Comment: In that case I would suggest editing the question to move away from the 'message box' topic and focus more closely on the 'font size' topic. I appreciate you do mention this on the first line, but I think the changing of the title and the focusing on the information you added as an edit would help.

Comment: I can do that. I used that title because I assumed most add-on developers would want a decent message box setup to show the user variable-width text messages. I was wondering how it is usually done. But there are other answers that would work for me. For example, if someone knows how to auto-size the window itself, the text could be roughly broken up with a function, then the window sized to fit around it.

Comment: That's true, it's just important to focus the question on what you're actually asking. If you want the general answers on how to create a message box, then I think this is a duplicate, if you want more specific answers on font size, then focus on that.

Comment: A solution to that post would have likely resolved my problem. If that makes it a duplicate, then it is. But it doesn't look like there actually is a solution. Or at least not an easy or obvious one. It seems strange to leave this type of feature out, given how dynamic and flexible Blender's UI system is at adapting to resizing. I guess it's something that isn't needed all that often. I might try to find the source code that deals with tool-tips to see if I can figure out anything useful.